SafeNet eToken 5110+ FIPS L2 - FastSSL EV Code Signing Certificate from FastSSL
FastSSL portal requires CSR code from the SafeNet Token. I can not find anywhere to generate the CSR using the token and SafeNet Authentication Client. Can anyone provide guidence?
I am trying to download my FastSSL EV Code Signing Certificate onto my SafeNet eToken 5110+ FIPS L2.
